# jQuery click event is not working on table

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

I'm having a table in my react application. I'm trying to implement click event like this:

```
$('#detailedTable tbody').on('click', 'tr', function() {
    //var row = $(this).parent()
    if ($(this).next('tr').hasClass('row-details')) {
        $(this).next().toggle();
        return;
    }
})
```

I placed this inside componentDidMount method.

This is my table:

```
<table className="table table-hover table-condensed table-detailed"
id="detailedTable" ref={node => this.table_el = node}>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th className="sorting_disabled wd-5p"></th>
            <th >Title</th>
            <th className="wd-15p">Channel</th>
            <th className="wd-10p">File Type</th>
            <th className="wd-15p">Uploaded</th>
            <th className="wd-20p">Process</th>
            <th className="wd-10p">Status</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    { this.state.MediaFiles.map((item, i) => (
    <tbody>
        <tr onClick={this.rowClick} id={i}>
            <td className="v-align-middle">
                <div className="checkbox">
                <input type="checkbox" value="3" id={"checkbox1" + i}/>
                <label htmlFor={"
```

But the click event is not getting fired. What is wrong?

Comment: Put an alert inside `$('#detailedTable tbody').on('click', 'tr', function() {` and see, if event listener is not working or you are traversing the DOM incorrectly

Comment: You really shouldn't use jquery with react. Not that it will not work, but there are many problems with such usage...

Comment: @MayankPandeyz why put `alert` when you can use the debugger?! :(

Comment: @MayankPandeyz I tried putting console. From that only I came to know that it doesn't work.

Comment: I'm just curious. You choose to use `onClick` for your `tr` but you choose to use jQuery for your `tbody`? I would suggest you use one way handling events and save yourself confusions in the future. Also, what @Dekel said about jQuery+react is true.

Answer (score 4):

Click event works perfectly with the following HTML:

```js
$('#detailedTable tbody').on('click', 'tr', function() {
  console.log('click works!');
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table className="table table-hover table-condensed table-detailed" id="detailedTable" ref={node => this.table_el = node}>
  <thead>
    <tr>
        <th className="sorting_disabled wd-5p">
        </th>
        <th>Title</th>
        <th className="wd-15p">Channel</th>
        <th className="wd-10p">File Type</th>
        <th className="wd-15p">Uploaded</th>
        <th className="wd-20p">Process</th>
        <th className="wd-10p">Status</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr onClick={this.rowClick} id={i}>
        <td className="v-align-middle">
            TBODY ITEM (click it)
        </td>
    </tr> 
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$(document).on('click', '#detailedTable tbody tr', function() {
  //var row = $(this).parent()
  if ($(this).next('tr').hasClass('row-details')) {
    $(this).next('tr').toggle();
    return;
  }
});
```

Comment: Only this seems to be working for me, I wonder why I can't just directly use the `#detailedTable tbody tr` in the selector..